# Problems with DataContext not loading updated entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've stumbled upon a strange problem which I can't wrap my head around.

I have two DataContexts in two different forms. I created two "Customer" entities (Customer A and Customer Z) in one form and saved them through the form's context. I then went back to the other form, where I manage orders. In this form, I can create an order and search for a customer (or his address).

```
        public void CustomerAddressSearched()
    {
        // Get all delivery addresses matching keyword            
        List<Address> addressList = customerModel.GetMatchingDeliveryAddresses(view.OrderSearchKeyword);

        // If there is no matching address
        if (addressList.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.SearchNoResult);
        }
        // If there is a single matching address
        else if (addressList.Count == 1)
        {
            activeOrder.Address = addressList[0];
            PopulateOrderAddressControls(addressList[0]);
            activeOrderIsSaved = false;
        }
        // If there is more than one matching address, open search result view for user to pick address
        else
        {
            using (var form = new CustomerSearchView(addressList))
            {
                if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    CustomerViewObject selectedCustomer = (CustomerViewObject)form.selectedCustomer;
                    activeOrder.Address = addressList.Where(a => a.Id == selectedCustomer.AddressId).FirstOrDefault();
                    activeOrder.AddressId = selectedCustomer.AddressId;
                    PopulateOrderAddressControls(activeOrder.Address);
                    activeOrderIsSaved = false;
                }
            }
        }

        EnableOrDisableControls();
    }
```

I searched for Customer and got a list with both customers. I went back to the customer form and changed the name of Customer A to Customer B, saved, then went back and searched again. Unfortunately, I got Customer A and Z as a result, not Customer B. Checked the database, Customer B is in it. I then picked Customer A for the order I created and saved it. Created a new one, searched again, and this time I got Customer B instead of A. I somehow need to use the "old" version once, otherwise the new one doesn't show. If this makes any sense.

So I checked

```
List<Address> addressList = customerModel.GetMatchingDeliveryAddresses(view.OrderSearchKeyword);
```

to see if there was something wrong with the way I retrieve the latest customer data.

```
        public List<Address> GetMatchingDeliveryAddresses(string keyword)
    {
        List<Address> addressList = new List<Address>();

        foreach (var c in context.Customers)
        {
            if (c.DateDeleted == null)
            {
                var result = c.Address.Where(a => (a.LastName.Contains(keyword) || a.Company.Contains(keyword)) && a.IsDeliveryAddress == true)
                                                    .OrderByDescending(a => a.DateEffective)
                                                    .FirstOrDefault();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    addressList.Add(result);
                }
            }
        }

        return addressList;
    }
```

Sure enough, when debugging and stopping at the foreach loop, I noticed the latest version (Customer B) was not loaded (if I didn't use it at least once or restarted the program/created a new context).

I put

```
            var list = context.Addresses.ToList();
```

right before the foreach loop just to check if he wouldn't load the new customer address at all, but all of a sudden it worked, the foreach loop loaded the newest customer version. I removed the line again and it stopped working. Put it back in, worked again. I guess my question is, why is the line above somehow refreshing my context, or whatever is happening?

Cheers!

### Edit

I started went to the customer directory where I had two customers (Customer E and Customer 3). I renamed them to Customer ASD and Customer 666. Went back to the order form and searched for Customer. It ran the following code:

```
        public List<Address> GetMatchingDeliveryAddresses(string keyword)
    {
        List<Address> addressList = new List<Address>();

        foreach (var c in context.Customers)
        {
            var result = c.Address.Where(a => (a.LastName.Contains(keyword) || a.Company.Contains(keyword)) && a.IsDeliveryAddress == true)
                                                    .OrderByDescending(a => a.DateEffective)
                                                    .FirstOrDefault();
            System.Console.WriteLine("PRE Name: " + result.LastName);
        }

        var list = context.Addresses.ToList();

        foreach (var c in context.Customers)
        {
            var result = c.Address.Where(a => (a.LastName.Contains(keyword) || a.Company.Contains(keyword)) && a.IsDeliveryAddress == true)
                                                    .OrderByDescending(a => a.DateEffective)
                                                    .FirstOrDefault();
            System.Console.WriteLine("POST Name: " + result.LastName);
        }
```

With the following output:

```
PRE Name: Customer E
PRE Name: Customer 3
POST Name: Customer ASD
POST Name: Customer 666
```

I don't get it.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed it might be a bit much. Look at the "Edit" part.

Comment: also, where is your context being created?  are you "Sharing" the context?

Comment: But "var list" is never used so I don't get how it refreshed the context, making the following foreach loop able to retrieve the latest address. If I remove the line, it stops working.

Comment: The context used to retrieve the customers is created when the form is initialized. I'm doing a context per form.

Comment: i wish i understood the issue... are you saying the data is changing?

Comment: i think you aren't managing your context correctly.  show the code where you save changes and when you create the context.

Comment: when you saved your changes your context should call SaveChanges and then CLOSE

Comment: is this a forms type app?  I'm getting the impression you are using a context per page and using it the entire time?  You don't open/close??  That is not a good idea and will bite you in multiple ways.

Comment: Yeah, most probably, he never disposes his context until the form is closed or something like that.

Comment: Turns out you were right, the code never made it to the dispose call for the customer directory context. But I still don't understand why it triggers such strange behaviour and how the line I added "fixed" it.

Comment: If you open two contexts, make changes to one, save them and dispose that context, do you need to "reload" the other one in order for it to retrieve the latest entries?

Comment: @Lahey Check my answer and see if this approach gonna fix the problem for you. Also, I've noticed that `Gert Arnold` is looking at your question, I follow his `EF` related answers and he's very good so it will be best if he explains what's really going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is getting too many comments, so I'm gonna post an answer here, cause I'm pretty sure that's the reason why you have this.. problem.

From what you've wrote in the comments: `The context used to retrieve the customers is created when the form is initialized. I'm doing a context per form.` it's getting clear that you are creating the context along with the form itself (probably in the constructor) and this is bad for many reasons. There are a lot of articles why you should NOT do that, but here we are talking for one certain problem and that's obviously the fact that your context is not changing until you close the form.

Now for your last comment - `Turns out you were right, the code never made it to the dispose call for the customer directory context. But I still don't understand why it triggers such strange behaviour and how the line I added "fixed" it.`

The reason is that `DbContext` is keeping track on all the changes that you make until the current context is alive, but it's just an expression tree (you could check what an expression tree is if you like) and in order to have some real data from that you need to execute certain calls. One of which is `ToList()` which forces the execution of the changes, but the quotes are really in place here, due to the fact that it's not how you are supposed to do it.

To keep it short. If you are not going to use any sort of data access layer, and just gonna use the `DbContext` directly inside your forms you should remove the context creation from the constructor (or where it is right now) and create new context each time (most probably for each method) that need to use. And in order to get rid of this problem you should wrap up tour code in `using` statement like so :

```
public List<Address> GetMatchingDeliveryAddresses(string keyword)
{
  using( var context = new MyEntitiesContext())
  {
    List<Address> addressList = new List<Address>();

    foreach (var c in context.Customers)
    {
        var result = c.Address.Where(a => (a.LastName.Contains(keyword) || a.Company.Contains(keyword)) && a.IsDeliveryAddress == true)
                                                .OrderByDescending(a => a.DateEffective)
                                                .FirstOrDefault();
        System.Console.WriteLine("PRE Name: " + result.LastName);
    }

    foreach (var c in context.Customers)
    {
        var result = c.Address.Where(a => (a.LastName.Contains(keyword) || a.Company.Contains(keyword)) && a.IsDeliveryAddress == true)
                                                .OrderByDescending(a => a.DateEffective)
                                                .FirstOrDefault();
        System.Console.WriteLine("POST Name: " + result.LastName);
    }
}
```

And that should be all.

Comment: Wrapping my code in using statements is actually what I've done in the  rest of the application, but since this didn't work well with lazy loading, I tried another approach. Seemed to work fine, until I ran into the problem above. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Lahey I'm pretty sure, that the `using` directive is not directly related to the performance issue you have. The only thing that `using` really does is making sure that the context is disposed after we are finished. Nothing less, nothing more. I would search the reasons for the lazy loading issues elsewhere. I'm just guessing of course but maybe you are not using the full potential of the SQL server and you are doing more of the data manipulation in your code. I found out (at least for me) that this is the main reason for poor performance.